# Расположение элементов в кастомной view

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-view, android-customview

Необходимо создать наследника RelativeLayout, внутри которого расположить 3 textView(№1, №2, №3). №1 в левом верхнем углу RL, №2 слева RL и под №1, а №3 справа от №1 или №2, в зависимости от того, что шире. Но ширину textView №1 и №2 я могу узнать только после того, как они отрисовались. Сделал вот так.

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    if(max(tv1.width, tv2.width) == tv1.width){
        (tv3.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams).addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_END,  R.id.tv_other_message_name)
    } else {
        (tv3.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams).addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_END,  R.id.tv_other_message_text)
    }
    tv3.requestLayout()
}
```

Но мне кажется, что это неправильный вариант, onDraw по идее предназначен для отрисовки элементов, а по другому как сделать - не знаю.
Хотел бы услышать комментарии по поводу того, как я сделал, и можно ли сделать правильней.

EDIT:

Обнаружил такой серьезный недостаток своего способа - вызов метода onDraw зацикливается. Тогда точно нужен какой то другой способ.

Comment: `TextView` добавляются программно?

Comment: @Flippy да, программно

Comment: они все добавляются единожды?

Comment: да, в конструкторе добавляются

Comment: @Art7 попробуйтев методе onLayout сделать

Comment: после добавления всех вью вызывайте `post` и передайту туда `Runnable` с вашим кодом. внутри метода `run` смело берите размеры.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать так:

```
addView(...)
addView(...)
addView(...)
post(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        // ваш код 
    }
}
```